# Plotting real part of a complex function with a condition

Tags: plotting, complex

`SWrss` is a complex function of `L` and `U` so I did

```
WW = Re[SWrss]
ContourPlot[WW > -0.5, {L, -1, -1/6}, {U, 1/6, 10}]
```

and gives error as

> ContourPlot::plnr: WW > -0.5 is not a machine-size real number at {L,
>   U} = \ {-1.,0.16666666666666666`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `SWrss`? Share the complete thing to get a positive response.

Comment: It too long to write here. It a function that has imaginary parts

Comment: You should check out `RegionFunction`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP  Indeed so.  Thanks for catching my typo.  My earlier comment should read, "The syntax is incorrect. Use `WW == -0.5` or `WW`."

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
f[z_] :=  Cos[z]^4
ContourPlot[Re[f[L + I U]], {L, -5, 5}, {U, -5, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{L, U}, Re[f[L + I U]] > -5], ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]